# How to pass arguments in mup config for meteor run command?

Tags: meteor, mup

Mup version (`1.4.3`):

```
module.exports = {
    servers: {

    },

    meteor: {
        // TODO: change app name and path
        name: 'e-commerce',
        path: '../../store',    //diff
        servers: {
            // one: {},
            two: {},
            three: {},
            four: {},
            five: {},
            six: {},
            seven: {}
        },

        buildOptions: {
            serverOnly: true,
            cleanAfterBuild: false,
        },

        env: {
            // TODO: Change to your app's url
            // If you are using ssl, it needs to start with https://
            ROOT_URL: 'https://someurl.com',
            MONGO_URL: 'xxx',
        },

        docker: {
            // change to 'kadirahq/meteord' if your app is not using Meteor 1.4
            //image: 'abernix/meteord:base',
            image: 'abernix/meteord:node-8.4.0-base'
            // imagePort: 80, // (default: 80, some images EXPOSE different ports)
        },
        deployCheckWaitTime: 80,
        enableUploadProgressBar: true
    }
};
```

Output of commmand after 2gb / 8 g is filled

`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

I have detailed my error in meteor forum [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/fatalprocessoutofmemory-help/42574)

Turns out not enough memory is located and i need to increase memory as included in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006869/meteor-app-ran-with-pm2-fatal-error-call-and-retry-last-allocation-failed-jav/48166231#48166231)

I need to pass environment Variable when mup runs my app, how do i put that example `main.js --node-args="--max-old-space-size=6144"`

**How do i pass arugments with mup config ?**
Any suggestion or help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don' t think that you can without forking `abernix/meteord:base` as the [run_app.js](https://github.com/abernix/meteord/blob/master/base/scripts/run_app.sh) simply runs the `main.js` file with no arguments.

Comment: @MasterAM is it possible to set this as an environment variable?

Comment: Might be possible using `NODE_OPTIONS`. See [the cli reference](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_options_options) for more details (states that it was added in node v8.0, so it probably requires Meteor v1.6+).

Answer (score 0):

I just forked the repo and modified and created a new image. Is running already. Thanks for the hint